# Is it possible to add an automatic redirect url to a slideshow slide?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slider, slideshow

I have a client that insists on having a splash page with background music when someone visits his website. He is also stuck on flash effects but still wants the website working on apple products such as iPhone, iPad etc.

He wants this splash page to automatically send the visitor to the "main" page after 4 seconds.

So! using a layerslider with only one slide containing several images which he refers as cool I managed to get flash out of the picture and got the background music playing too, so he is happy with that.

I set the slide to 20 seconds but what I need now is to get this slide to redirect to the main page.

Anyone have an idea on how to do that?

PS it is a wordpress hosted website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any event handler provided by your plugin which signifies the end of slider run? Or a callback. If yes, you can use it to find the end of the slider and redirect it to your main page.

Since it's a plugin, there must be such a handler. Please check as the plugin you are using is not free and i can't access it documentation. (Not available freely.)

Comment: might be worth a try, sounds like it could work.. But do you mean add "onfocus=_redirectToMain();" directly to the image?

Comment: Sorry, that won't work imo. Please see my edited answer. Hard to answer it as the plugin you are using is not free.

Comment: Yes there is an event_callback.html file, but its a little overclass for me.. can you tell me what needs to be done?

Comment: So, can you tell me how is this callback file used in your code? Just trying to get an idea of how this is used so that you can add an event to it.

Comment: Ive never done anything like this before, dont know what I should be looking for, please have a look  http://webelite.se/?page_id=121

Comment: It is displaying nothing. Please attach a demo.

Comment: I think I understand, cbAnimStop: Fireing when the slider finished a slide change (animation end). I can add a function here cbAnimStop:function(data) { } telling the slider to redirect after animations ends right?

Comment: Yes, that's the one :). This or `cbStop` will help you. Let me see if i can post the functions for you.

Comment: Can you tell me how are you initializing the slider?

Comment: the slider starts when you visit the site, so should be unload

Comment: You should do like: `$('your_id_here').layerSlider({cbAnimStop:function(){location.href='YOUR_MAIN_PAGE_LINK_HERE';}});`. `your_id_here` is the id of the div which has the slider, `YOUR_MAIN_PAGE_LINK_HERE` is the link to your main page.